# have two lists and need to convert them into query

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

I have two separate lists which are giving me the results, I want to convert those separate lists in one query, i did used `listoquery` from `cflib` , but it does only for 1, not for more queries.

How can i do it, any clue, can't use `queryappend`, because i am on `lucee`.

```
<cffunction name="listToQuery" access="public" returntype="query" output="false" 
    hint="Converts a list to a single-column query.">
    <cfargument name="list" type="string" required="yes" hint="List to convert.">
    <cfargument name="delimiters" type="string" required="no" default="," hint="Things that separate list elements.">
    <cfargument name="column_name" type="string" required="no" default="column" hint="Name to give query column.">

    <cfset var query = queryNew(arguments.column_name)>
    <cfset var index = ''>

    <cfloop list="#arguments.list#" index="index" delimiters="#arguments.delimiters#">
        <cfset queryAddRow(query)>
        <cfset querySetCell(query,arguments.column_name,index)>
    </cfloop>

    <cfreturn query>
</cffunction>
```

or i have a for loop

like this

https://trycf.com/gist/28e9f2b8ff2992e0dc9f78709a0d2041/lucee5?theme=monokai

Comment: Either merge the lists into one, or pass in an array of lists. Then and an extra loop to iterate through each list before appending the values.

Comment: Can you provide sample data for those two lists? And can you describe what the result is supposed to look like? Right now, it's unclear to me what you expect.

Comment: sure, here is my fiddle https://trycf.com/gist/306dbd4229709a225b11093eafc4ed93/lucee5?theme=monokai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<cfscript>

    list1 = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8';
    list2 = '5,5,5,5,7,7,4,4';

    result = queryNew("");

    queryAddListAsNewColumn(result, "id", list1);
    queryAddListAsNewColumn(result, "name", list1);
    queryAddListAsNewColumn(result, "cid", list2);

    writeDump(result);

    /*
     * Adds the provided list to the query as a new column. Automatically expands query records.
    */
    function queryAddListAsNewColumn(query, columnName, list) {

        // prepare list data
        LOCAL.data      = listToArray(ARGUMENTS.list);
        LOCAL.dataCount = arrayLen(LOCAL.data);

        // add new column to query
        queryAddColumn(ARGUMENTS.query, ARGUMENTS.columnName);

        // expand query if list to add exceeds the current record count
        LOCAL.rowDelta = (LOCAL.dataCount - ARGUMENTS.query.recordCount);
        if (LOCAL.rowDelta > 0) {
            queryAddRow(ARGUMENTS.query, LOCAL.rowDelta);
        }

        // add list data to each cell in the new column
        for (LOCAL.i = 1; LOCAL.i <= LOCAL.dataCount; LOCAL.i++) {
            querySetCell(ARGUMENTS.query, ARGUMENTS.columnName, LOCAL.data[LOCAL.i], LOCAL.i);
        }

        // returning isn't necessary because the passed query argument is a reference, return whatever suits your needs
        return ARGUMENTS.query;
    }

</cfscript>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the two lists have the same length, you can do something like this.

```
myQuery = QueryNew(dummy, varchar);
QueryAddColumn(myQuery, Column1, varchar, ListToArray(List1);
QueryAddColumn(myQuery, Column2, varchar, ListToArray(List2);
QueryDeleteColumn(myQuery, dummy);
```

Comment: it does not work if you have for loop, and addColumn will not work, i tried using querysetcell but that says column already existsing

Comment: this is one such issue can't seems to find a way to it

Comment: soemthing, but i can't seems to found a solution, can you provide any sample or idea in gist

Comment: Nope, I'm wrong. They do want two columns according to the gist @SignUp - Did you try the above? Also, the code and info in the gist should be in your question.